# Fading in via CSS transition doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to `animate` a page element using CSS `transition` on `opacity` property. Fading out works properly, but Fading in doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

**Some facts are really strange**:

- Without using `.no-display` class everything works as expected (but I should use it).
- Replaying function's commands in browser console *does work* as expected (but function does not).

**The code:**

*HTML*

```
<p><a href="javascript:fadeIn()">Fade in</a></p>
<p><a href="javascript:fadeOut()">Fade out</a></p>
<div class="no-display invisible" id="square"></div>
```

*CSS*

```
.no-display {
    display: none;
}

.invisible {
    opacity: 0;
}

#square {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid black;

    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease;
    -ms-transition: opacity 2s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity 2s ease;
    transition: opacity 2s ease;
}
```

*JavaScript*

```
function fadeIn() {
    square.classList.remove("no-display");
    square.classList.remove("invisible");
}

function fadeOut() { 
    square.classList.add("invisible");
    setTimeout(function() { square.classList.add("no-display"); }, 2000 );
}
```

**Or:** http://jsfiddle.net/V2Sar/6/.

Note, I can't use any frameworks such as jQuery. I have to work only with pure JavaScript.

Comment: You cadd add and remove the animation classes. Then the fading effect would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way to trigger CSS transitions with JS is to toggle classnames, and the easy way to do that is through the [classList API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.classList).

#### js

```js
var square = document.getElementById("square");
function fadeIn() {
    square.classList.remove("invisible");
}

function fadeOut() { 
    square.classList.add("invisible");
}
```

#### css

```css
#square {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 2s ease;
}
#square.invisible {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V2Sar/5/

Also, make sure your scripts are at the end of the `<body>` so you don't need to worry about whether the DOM is constructed yet (separate option in jsfiddle for this).

The browser support isn't great (no support in IE9) but there is a shim available at https://github.com/eligrey/classList.js

Let me know if this isn't good enough for you and I'll post some alternatives as well.

Comment: Updated the question; please look at bullet list.

Comment: @gxoptg Looks like a race condition, check out http://jsfiddle.net/V2Sar/7/ - where I use a timeout of 0 to let the browser repaint (because of `display: block;`) before toggling the class

Comment: @gxoptg The same concept applies to toggling classnames, if you were wondering: http://jsfiddle.net/V2Sar/8/

Answer (score 0):

The only problem is "display: none;". Simply replace it with 'visibility: hidden'.

The reason is that 'display: none' doesn't build the resulting element in the DOM. As such, it cannot fade in something that does not exist. When its created, its created in a visible way.

'visibility: hidden', however, does build the resulting element in the DOM, simply doesn't show it. Because it exists, it can fade in when required.

Comment: Note that it should be "visibility: hidden;" since "none" is not a valid value for the visibility property.